# Safari - Session storage

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, safari

Having an issue with Safari in storing and loading session variables.

Currently, session vars are being held in a server-side session using HttpServletRequest

`request.getSession().setAttribute("wellSelection", uid);`

This works in Firefox, IE and Chrome, but not for Safari. I've had a look at the safari documentation for Client-Side storage, but this is not really what I am looking for.

Has anyone found a way around this?

*I am using Tomcat 5.5 for server side deployment*

Comment: Hey, I am having the same problem... how did you solved it?

Comment: Sudh, I used HTML 5 session storage rather than the Java implementation.